# Development Libraries on CentOS Missing from yum grouplist

Tags: linux, cmake, yum, centos6

I'm trying to compile some software that requires the use of the "Development Libraries"

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"
yum install gcc-g++ git-core wget links zip unzip unrar
yum install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-devel
yum install openssl
yum install cmake (Must be CMake ≥ 2.8.12)
```

One obstacle was getting cmake higher than 2.6 on CentOS 6.2 x64... found out I just had to run

> yum install cmake28

my issue with it is it installed **cmake28-2.8.11.2-1.el6.x86_64** still not the one it wants but I can't seem to get any higher with out I guess self compiling which I hear it's a nightmare.

ignoring the fact that when I type

> yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"

it returns

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirrors.rit.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: yum.singlehop.com
Setting up Group Process
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Warning: Group Development Libraries does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

**Warning: Group Development Libraries does not exist.**

So I'm at a stale mate and I think because the Libraries do not exist for me to install I cannot get cmake to well work... I have cmake installed but when I try to issue

```
[root@serve5 build]# cmake ../ -DPREFIX=/home/`echo $USER`/server
-bash: cmake: command not found
```

but as you can see here

```
[root@serve5 build]# yum update cmake28
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirrors.rit.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: yum.singlehop.com
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

or

```
[root@serve5 build]# yum install cmake28 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirrors.rit.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: yum.singlehop.com
Setting up Install Process
Package cmake28-2.8.11.2-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So I'm kinda stumped and I'm certain it's because of a resource I am missing that's in the Libraries that no longer exist.

Also if this is the wrong exchange site sorry which is the correct one for unix/linux problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead: `yum groupinstall "Additional Development"`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an error with the repositories as well. The following resolved it for me

```
$ sudo su
# vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
```

I changed enabled=1 to enabled=0 and :wq

I create a small shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "installing essential tools and libraries for CentOS" ;

yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools" ;
yum -y groupinstall "Development Libraries" ;
yum -y install gcc-g++ git-core wget links zip unzip unrar ;
yum -y install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-devel ;
yum -y install openssl ;
yum -y install cmake ;

echo "Done."
```

I ran the script and everything installed successfully. Then, I was able to use yum to install clamav and everything else I wanted to install so far.

Answer (score 0):

> wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.12.1-Linux-i386.tar.gz

Unpack and copy it to /usr/local

```
sudo tar xvfz cmake-2.8.12.1-Linux-i386.tar.gz

cd cmake-2.8.4-Linux-i386

sudo cp -R cmake-2.8.12.1-Linux-i386/* /usr/local
```

turns out it was easier than it looked....

also made sure to first run

> yum remove cmake28

Development Libraries are missing but I guess they are installed somewhere else maybe merged with Development Tools.